# How to pass custom WebSocketCloseStatus while closing WebSocket c#

Tags: c#, .net, websocket

Currently I use the below function to close the websocket

```
await webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, string.Empty, CancellationToken.None);
```

here are the possible values that can be provided as `WebSocketCloseStatus`

```
namespace System.Net.WebSockets
{
    public enum WebSocketCloseStatus
    {
        NormalClosure = 1000,
        EndpointUnavailable = 1001,
        ProtocolError = 1002,
        InvalidMessageType = 1003,
        Empty = 1005,
        InvalidPayloadData = 1007,
        PolicyViolation = 1008,
        MessageTooBig = 1009,
        MandatoryExtension = 1010,
        InternalServerError = 1011
    }
}
```

But I want to provide custom number as websocketclosestatus while closing the websocket such as 4200, 4201, 4202, etc.. Because my source expects me to close the websocket with these custom numbers. Each number has its own meaning.

Any thoughts ?

Edit : Note, I'm not using any 3rd party library/Nuget packages to connect/receive/close websocket, I'm using the `System.Net.WebSockets` library alone.

Comment: You need to inherit the WebSocket class and then override the enumeration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use casting to send custom statuses:
 `client.CloseAsync((WebSocketCloseStatus)4005, "Empty", cts.Token);`
[image: Fiddler]
I don't know which framework you use and checked only classic .Net framework (v4.8).
Parameter `closeStatus` passes from `CloseAsync` ([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/ClientWebSocket.cs,335)) deeper to a [function](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketBase.cs,754) with first validation this parameter. This [validation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketHelpers.cs,412) checks only that the status is in valid range (not beetween 0 and 999 and not has some special statuses 1006 or 1015). Then deeper through function calls to `CloseOutputAsync` ([source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketBase.cs,508)). Here this parameter is assigned to property of object `WebSocketOperation.CloseOutputOperation` - `m_CloseOutputOperation.CloseStatus = closeStatus;` This property is cast to `ushort` `payloadBuffer.CloseStatus.CloseStatus = (ushort)CloseStatus;` then it goes output in wire.
There is no checks that this parameter should have a value only from enum list.

Comment: Thank you, worked well. Simple and easy method, no need to inherit `WebSocket` class and override the `WebSocketCloseStatus` enum as suggested in comment.